# annotation - cannot find symbol

Tags: java, android-studio-3.0

Android 3.2.1

In build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

AppBarLayout.java snippet:

```
@C0107b(a = AppBarLayout.Behavior.class)
public class AppBarLayout extends LinearLayout {
    /* renamed from: a */
    boolean f306a;
    /* renamed from: b */
    final List<C0096a> f307b;
    /* renamed from: c */
    private int f308c = -1;
    /* renamed from: d */
    private int f309d = -1;
    /* renamed from: e */
    private int f310e = -1;
    /* renamed from: f */
    private float f311f;
    /* renamed from: g */
    private int f312g = 0;
    /* renamed from: h */
    private an f313h;

    /* renamed from: android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$1 */
    class C00911 implements C0069r {
        /* renamed from: a */
        final /* synthetic */ AppBarLayout f274a;

        C00911(AppBarLayout appBarLayout) {
            this.f274a = appBarLayout;
        }

        /* renamed from: a */
        public final an mo42a(View view, an anVar) {
            return AppBarLayout.m394a(this.f274a, anVar);
        }
    }

    public static class Behavior extends HeaderBehavior<AppBarLayout> {
        /* renamed from: a */
        private int f291a;
        /* renamed from: b */
        private boolean f292b;
        /* renamed from: c */
        private boolean f293c;
        /* renamed from: d */
        private C0195r f294d;
        /* renamed from: e */
        private int f295e = -1;
        /* renamed from: f */
        private boolean f296f;
        /* renamed from: g */
        private float f297g;
        /* renamed from: h */
        private WeakReference<View> f298h;
        /* renamed from: i */
        private C0095a f299i;

        protected static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {
            public static final Creator<SavedState> CREATOR = C0446c.m1463a(new C00941());
            /* renamed from: a */
```

In class `CoordinatorLayout.class`

```
public class CoordinatorLayout extends ViewGroup implements C0112p {
    /* renamed from: a */
    static final String f381a;

...
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    /* renamed from: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$b */
    public @interface C0107b {
        /* renamed from: a */
        Class<? extends Behavior> m469a();
    }
```

But I get compile error:

```
myproject\widget\AppBarLayout.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
```

Symbol "**a**" is has red color

Comment: does the C0107b annotation have a variable (editable) that's called a ?

Comment: @Stultuske I updated my post

Comment: so, you have no variable a, yet you try to set one ... how does this strike you as odd?

Comment: because there is an m469a variable in your annotation type

Comment: @Stultuske this work. @C0107b(m469a = AppBarLayout.Behavior.class) . Thanks